# Git rebase from beginning

Tags: git, git-rebase

**git log** shows something like this:

```
commit hash3
New feature

commit hash2
bugfix

commit hash1
Initial commit
```

I want to squeeze first two commits, into one "Initial commit", to clean history. If i do:

```
git rebase -i hash1
```

It doesn't show first commit, so that I could squeeze bugfix commit into it. If i mark bugfix commit with "s", it says there is no previous commit to squeeze to. So how do i make git rebase -i, so that it shows whole history, including the first commit, so i could squeeze it?

I know I can just remove repository, make new one and have one single commit, but i do want to have commits "initial commit" and "new feature" in history.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Kerrek! This seems to be it. I'll try that in a moment.

Comment: (All I did was search the internet for "git rebase include first commit"...)